# Elegant way of obtaining the position of a certain char in txt File in C

Tags: c

Im practicing C right now. I want to read in a txt File and find the line and the place in that line for the char 'X'. Is there a more elegant way then iterating over fgets for the line number and then iterating over getchar ?

Comment: You could just use getchar() and advance the line numbers on encountering '\n', won't need to allocate a buffer either.

Comment: There is nothing inelegant about iterating over calls to `getchar`.  Calling `fgets` is a bit kludgy.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus `getchar` or `fscanf` will both use exactly the same number of `read` calls.  Stdio is buffered.

Comment: @WilliamPursell So `getchar` won't be reading one character at a time from the file and then again do that? Could you please explain or provide a link to read.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus Internally fscanf would have to iterate over the file to get the chars and then output it into a buffer anyway and calling getchar() in a loop does the same, just without an extra buffer since you consume every character directly.

Comment: @git-bruh my doubt is about the number of times the file will be accessed by `getchar` and `scanf` - is that number same for both the cases?

Comment: Map file to memory and use `memchr()`

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus In case we're accessing stdin and the file descriptor for that is already open for us, so we don't deal with opening/closing it hence they would "access" the file the same number of times. For opening a file via path the code would be `FILE *fp = fopen("path"); fgetc(fp);` and would act the same. We close the fd after looping over it till fgetc tells us.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus That number is the same for each case.  When `getchar` is called the first time, a read will access the file and fill a buffer.  The next several times it is called (probably the next 4095 times, or the next 8191 times), a character will be returned from that internal buffer.  `scanf` does the same thing, but parses the buffer a bit.

Comment: @WilliamPursell git-bruh Thanks for this clear comment.

Comment: `getchar()` in gnu libc, unless I'm mistaken, ultimately does the macro `_IO_getwc_unlocked(_fp)` (line 171 of [libio.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/libio.h;h=b7cfe1cb7cbd3c9acb84e9607f476f76e542f495;hb=HEAD)) which pretty much amounts to `return *ptr++;`

Comment: " Is there a more elegant way then iterating over fgets for the line number and then iterating over getchar ?" --> How about a more elegant way to find an elegant way?  --> Write code that is _fully_ functional, post it and then ask for elegant  improvements.  Perhaps on [COde Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?  It is better than starting with no code, as we have here.  I am sure you will get many good ideas.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty much the only way to do it.

Of course, you can practice using any of the file-access and string-manipulation functions, to understand their beauty or their limitations. But essentially, that is it - read characters one by one. Whether you do it "by hand", or by calling a specialized function (which will do that for you).

You might understand it better if you extend the problem to find all occurencies of some character.

Note: many times, computers to things exactly like the humans do, but faster. Why? Because the programmer implements in the SW the same algorithm which is in their mind. From there, optimizations can be done.

Just think about it: How would you find the first "X" in a (random) book?